# most simple way to password protect a web page in angular material

Tags: angular, angular-material, password-protection

I have a question regarding how to password protect a web page.
I used angular material to create a webpage that will talk to back-end service to query information. I also add an admin sub-page to do website configuration.

I'd like to make the admin page protected by password.
This protection can be a very simple security feature, nothing complicated is required.
Just a token that only a few people knows, once they enter the valid token the admin page will show.

I looked a few ways:

1. .htaccess and .htpassword
2. embed a java script as header in admin.component.html
3. angular router link authentication

1 and 2 do not work for me
3 seems to be an overkill for my requirement.

Any idea how to make a simple password protected webpage?
Also if I have to go with 3, it will protect any page re-routed to admin page.
However if I directly enter [www.mysite.com/admin](http://www.mysite.com/admin), will it still be protected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use auth guards.

Try to look at users: https://angular-authguard-jwt-duxyen.stackblitz.io/users

You can't, it's guarded until you log in.

We have set an authGuard on our users route.

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'users', component: UsersComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] }
];
```

This is what authorizes what's visible and what is not. If the user can not activate, their tossed to `/login`.

```js
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private _authService: AuthService, private router: Router){}

  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
      if(this._authService.loggedIn()){
        return true;
      }else{
        this.router.navigate(['/login']);
        return false;
      }
  }
}
```

Auth service returns `true/false` for `canActivate` when asked for. `true/false` depends if user has "secretToken" stored on their machine.

```js
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

  constructor() { }

  loggedIn(){
    let hasToken = false;
    if (localStorage.getItem('token') == 'secretToken'){
      hasToken = true;
    }
    return hasToken;
  }

  getToken(){
    return localStorage.getItem('token');
  }

}
```

We use store a token to localStorage to keep track if user is authenticated to access our `/users` route.

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css'],
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  loginUserData: User = { username: '', password: '' };
  allowedUsername = 'Mike';
  allowedPassword = '123';
  constructor(private _auth: AuthService, private router: Router) {}
  ngOnInit() {}

  loginUser() {
    if (
      this.loginUserData.username == this.allowedUsername &&
      this.loginUserData.password == this.allowedPassword
    ) {
      console.log('login success');
      localStorage.setItem('token', 'secretToken');
      localStorage.setItem('is_admin', 'true');
      this.router.navigate(['/home']);
    }
  }
}

export interface User {
  username: string;
  password: string;
}
```

Using a token is quite common client side authentication. In our case, the token is hard-coded but if you want to expand this to an actual authentication process you could. I removed it for simplicity (hint: google JWT token if you're interested).

Basically after login, we put a key/value pair on clients localStorage. `key` is token and it's `value` is "scretToken". We put it there once user successfully logs in for the first time. We then redirect user to `/users` url. On arriving to `/users` our `authGuard` kicks in, checking if client has token "scretToken" on their machine. If they have they can see the contents. If not, their tossed back to `/login`.

Because we're storing token in localStorage, even if user refreshes or changes tab, their still authenticated. If they clear their browsing data manually the token is removed. If they logout with our logout button, we also delete the token from localStorage.

Log in here: https://angular-authguard-jwt-duxyen.stackblitz.io/login

Username: `Mike`, Password: `123`

Working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-authguard-jwt-duxyen?file=src%2Fapp%2Flogin%2Flogin.component.ts

Comment: Thank you very much for your clear explanations and examples!